# Turtle only completes one iteration of a loop and stops at done()

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I am trying Python turtle and I am facing this error:

```
pencolor(col) File"<string>",line 5,in pencolor turtle.Terminator
```

Here is my code:

```py
from turtle import*
import colorsys

speed(0)
pensize(3)
bgcolor('black')
hue=0.0

for i in range(300):
    col=colorsys.hsv_to_rgb(hue,1,1)
    pencolor(col)
    hue+=0.005
    circle(5-i,100)
    lt(80)
    circle(5-i,100)
    rt(100)
    done()
```

Comment: That's not an error. That's just one line of the whole error, showing where the error is, but not what the error is. You need to put the full stacktrace in your question. And also your title needs to be a question, or describe something about the issue you're having - right now your question title says nothing at all about what your specific issue is. The [tour] and [ask] pages might help you. Also when I run your code I do not even get any errors; your code needs to be a [mre]. The code you posted here must not be the same code that is producing that error.

Comment: Why are you calling `done()` from inside this loop? Shouldn't `done()` be called after the `for`-block has already finished?

Comment: Your program is working as expected.  You only see that when you kill the program using `Ctrl-C`.  It's telling you that you terminated the program, which of course you did.   Unindent the `done()` line (move it to the left edge), and it all works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is calling [`done()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.done) in the loop. Let's check the docs for this function:

> `turtle.done()`
> Starts event loop - calling Tkinter's `mainloop` function. Must be the last statement in a turtle graphics program. Must *not* be used if a script is run from within IDLE in -n mode (No subprocess) - for interactive use of turtle graphics.

There's no real exceptional error in your code per se, only a logical one related to misunderstanding `done`. It only runs through the first iteration of the loop before blocking on `done` forever. When you terminate the program, turtle is still in the midst of its loop and doesn't exit cleanly, so whatever routine it's in at the time looks like it caused the error.

The solution is to move `done` outside of the loop:

```py
from turtle import *
import colorsys

speed(0)
pensize(3)
bgcolor("black")
hue = 0.0

for i in range(300):
    col = colorsys.hsv_to_rgb(hue, 1, 1)
    pencolor(col)
    hue += 0.005
    circle(5 - i, 100)
    lt(80)
    circle(5 - i, 100)
    rt(100)

done()  # <--
```

This is one of many gotchas that makes turtle a bit less user-friendly for beginners than you'd think.

In the interest of avoiding other gotchas, I would avoid the `*` wildcard import. This dumps dozens of turtle functions into your script's namespace which can clash with your custom-defined functions, and create confusion between instance and functional interfaces, leading to hours of debugging agony. Better practice is to use only the `import turtle` statement at the top of your file, or explicitly list your imported functions instead of using `*`.

Better still is to import `from turtle import Screen, Turtle`, instantiate your turtle with `t = Turtle()`, and draw with `t` henceforth, even if it's only a single turtle.

Finally, prefer using the long form of turtle commands unless you have difficulty typing. `right` and `penup` are much more comprehensible than `rt` and `pu`.

I also formatted your code with [Black](https://black.vercel.app/), which I recommend doing before posting.

Comment: Yes done() was a problem now my code works correctly.